# Why can't I remap `gc` to `gc` and then `gv`?

Tags: key-bindings

My vimrc already has the very useful mapping

```
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv
```

I'm using the TComment plugin, and I'd like to also do something like

```
vmap gc gcgv
```

to re-highlight a visual selection after toggling `gc`.

But, as written, it just seems to prevent `gc` from working. `vnoremap` gives the same result.

Is there a way to do this with a simple mapping? Or should I write a function for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, you either defined a recursive mapping (`vmap`), or one that doesn't know that `gc` is supposed to comment something (`vnoremap`).

Solution: do what `gc` does (if you look at it with `:verbose vmap gc`), and add `gv` to it as you want:

```
:xmap gc <Plug>TComment_gcgv
```

It does look strange. Maybe that's why other plugins use a format like `<Plug>(some_code)` ?

Also note that (un)commenting may change the text "bounding box" and it won't necessarily correspond to the visual selection *before* the operation.

Comment: All this time I assumed `gc` only worked linewise anyway...